# How do I teleport someone who enters a specific tunnel on Minecraft 1.17.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map on Minecraft 1.17.1 and I'm tying to make a challenge where you need to go through the correct tunnel, if you go through the wrong one you'll get teleported to the start.

I don't know how to do it, so I "tried" using the execute command but I don't know how to really use it.

Comment: I'm not someone that develops lots of things in MC but wouldn't it work to just have a pressure plate that when pressed throws a command that sends a command that tps your player?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved with a command block and the `tp` command:

```
tp @p[distance=..4] x y z
```

Where `x`, `y`, and `z` are the respective coordinates of your starting position.

---

Give yourself a command block with:

```
give @s command_block
```

Place it where it can be concealed (e.g. under a block in the tunnel) and set it's configuration to:

- Block Type: Repeat
- Condition: Unconditional
- Redstone: Always Active
- Command Input: `tp @p[distance=..4] x y z`

  - Where `x`, `y`, and `z` are the respective coordinates of your starting position.

Comment: This is a [tag:minecraft-java-edition] question. You seem to have posted a Bedrock Edition screenshot, and a command that hasn't worked on Java Edition since 1.13.

Comment: @pppery oops, in my multi-tasking state I failed to swap the syntax over. The UI for the command block, IIRC, is the same in Java edition though. However, I'm just going to remove it because I can't confirm for another few hours.

Comment: The correct java edition syntax is `/tp @p[distance=..4] x y z`. Whether you use `/tp` or `/teleport` doesn't matter.

Comment: @pppery thanks, I'm still new to Java edition; thanks for the clarity!